# SSH prompting for the password despite of sharing the public key

Tags: ssh, openssh

I generated the keys using ssh-keygen. Then shared my public key to authorized_keys. It is prompting for the password despite of sharing the public key

Permission of authorized_keys

-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 397 Jul 26 18:24 authorized_keys

Kindly help

Comment: please share the output of ssh -vv ...

Answer (score 1):

The authorized keys must have 640 permission in order to be used, otherwise the sshd ignores it. Try `chmod 640 authorized_keys` and `chmod 700 .ssh` on the .ssh folder under the user you are trying to login with.

See an example here [SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)